# Is a list of user names or IDs in a custom profile field the best way to create a followers list?

Tags: users

If I wanted to have a user have "followers" whats the best way to keep track of those people?

Im thinking of a comma separated list of user names or IDs in a custom profile field and then just appending new users to the list when somebody is added as a follower. Is that a good way to do it or is there a better way?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with that data. If you wanted to produce a list of users followed by a particular user, it would be tricky if that data is stored in a single field for each user.

Comment: good for whom and for what?

Answer (score 0):

Yes a custom field with a list of ID's is a good idea, there are 3 options for it:

1. The list is of the followed users the current user is following.
2. The list is of the followers that follow the current user.
3. A combination of both, 2 custom fields, one for the followers of the current user and another custom field for the users he follows.

It will depend on the criteria for it, users can follow each other?
number 3 its the best option IMHO